# rotate movieclip by pressing and rotating another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have placed two movieclips one parent name "container" and a child inside container named holder. I want container to rotate by pressing/dragging the holder placed at the top right corner with mouse movement. The container should rotate from the center point.

Comment: What have you tried? In fact, rotation is already done around central point (anchor point), so you just need to provide a relevant play with `Math.atan2()` in a listener attached to `holder`.

Answer (score 0):

Here on Stack Overflow, we do not work for you and code for you.  We just answer **productive** questions that will help future users.

So what you would do is make a MouseEvent function and add the event to holder by `container.holder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK...)` and in the function you would put: `addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME...)` and in that enter frame event, you would put: `event.currentTarget.rotation += NUMBER` or `container.rotation += NUMBER` - Same Thing because the event's current target is `container`. Replace `NUMBER` with a number.

Not much is being done here, as you can see:

[image: Picture of what is being done.]

Comment: sorry here is my code http://pastebin.com/B71MbKM0 the problem is i want it to rate from the center point of the container not from the top left corner. any help will be greatly appreciated.